# dbt command to select only incremental models schema change

Tags: dbt

I want to write a dbt command that will select only incremental models that have had a schema change (ie a new column has been added to the source data). The idea is then that I could add that statement as a regular deployment job to do a full refresh on those models. I think some combination of using the state:modified option and other selectors would work, but I haven't had much luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

select only incremental models that have had a schema change since the last run

Answer (score 3):

The closest you will get is

```
state:modified.body,config.materialized:incremental
```

But you will get all SQL changes, not just schema changes.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to incorporate if the on_schema_change configuration triggers an error then do a --full-refresh within the command?

Comment: You could definitely try and build something into your orchestration layer, if that’s what you’re asking.